# Should scripts be put into angular.json or into index.html?

Tags: angular

With Angular you have two options to load scripts (js and css):

1. In the `index.html`: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css">`
2. In the `angular.json`: `"styles": ["node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css"]`

What's the advantage of each option? To my understanding, the things in `angular.json` are bundled together while the scripts linked in `index.html` are loaded dynamically. So it boils down to the discussion whether it's better to having prebundled scripts or loading them e.g. from a CDN? Or are there other benefits from putting scripts into `angular.json` e.g. of organizational nature? Is it "cleaner" for some reason?

Answer (score 13):

Basically this is designed intentionally by the Angular team. In short, yes you can use either and you won't see any difference for a simpler project. But there are few difference between both of them.

- An array of style/script files to add to the global context of the project if you add it in `angular.json` file will also be included in the bundle while build, where as if you define file/CDN in `index.html` this will load separately.
- As per my understanding, assets that load via index file will not get copied in the bundle, but rather, it will show in the network tab.
- Assets defined via `angular.json` file will have more features, such as -

  1. glob: A node-glob using input as base directory.
  2. input: A path relative to the workspace root.
  3. output: A path relative to outDir (default is dist/project-name). Because of the security implications, the CLI never writes files outside of the project output path.
  4. ignore: A list of globs to exclude.

For example -

```
{ "glob": "**/*", "input": "src/assets/", "output": "/assets/" },
```

or

```
{ "input": "src/external-module/styles.scss", "inject": false, "bundleName": "external-module" }
```

For more information, I strongly recommend you to read this -

- https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config